# Refresh indicator without scrollview

Tags: flutter

I know with a `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` `RefreshIndicator` just works natively but I want to use a `RefreshIndicator` on a page that doesn't scroll. Is this even possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 134):

You must do the following:

- Use a `SingleChildScrollView` with the property `physics` set to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.
- Make sure it's child has a height of the size of the screen, which you can get with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`.

The complete example:

```dart
classs MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          ),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related, I had a listview.builder somewhere in the widget tree and I just needed to use the physics AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() and the media query height in the container above it in order to achieve the same.

Comment: What if I want to a scroll view without using ListView ?PLZ tell! I have a future builder as child of refresh indicator which is scrollable

Comment: This will not work in almost all cases, because as soon as you have a toolbar at the top or at the bottom, the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` expression would give you the height of the whole screen, not the height between the toolbars, and your content will always overflow to the bottom. The correct asnwer is this one, it does not require to mess with the height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157637/662084

Answer (score 41):

Most of the other answers will work but they all have some downsides:

- Using a `SingleChildScrollView` without adjusting the height will cause the scrolling glow effect to be not at the bottom of the page.
- Setting the height to the maximum height of the current view (by using `MediaQuery` or a `LayoutBuilder`) will fix that, but there will be a render overflow when your content's height is bigger than the height of the available space.

Eventually, the following solution works perfectly without any problems:

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () {},
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: constraints.maxHeight
        ),
        child: Text("My Widget")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: This solution is the best so far, as you said when setting it to the screen height you will simply get render overflow, but with your answer the issue is totally handled

Comment: Almost correct but spaces after the My Widget text doesn't trigger refresh, use minWidth: constraints.maxWIdth to fix this issue.

Answer (score 33):

The `SingleChildScrollView` solution in other answers would work for most cases.

I had a use case* where it didn't work because the content inside the `SingleChildScrollView` wanted to expand to fill the remaining height. So the `SingleChildScrollView` and `Expanded` widgets contradicted each other.

What saved the day, in the end, was using a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverFillRemaining` widget.

**No custom widget size calculation was needed.**

[image: pull-to-refresh-with-custom-scroll-view]

Code:

```dart
class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () async {
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          },
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("No results found."),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can test this on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e442c6933c0e3a7e1e96d29fc0ad6727) as well.

*My use case:

[image: pull-to-refresh-complex-case]

Comment: this is way better than setting the height

Answer (score 22):

So in my case I wanted to display a placeholder in an empty list:

```
          RefreshIndicator(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Text("The list is empty"),
                ),
                ListView()
              ],
            ),
            onRefresh: () {},
          )
```

Comment: this is what i use as well. but for a widgets above the listview that requires users to tap on buttons, it does not work.

Comment: @chitgoks sorry didn't get you. Which "buttons" are you referring to?

Answer (score 11):

I aggree with others about `SingleChildScrollView` solution. However it will work differently on android and on ios.

On android all is well but on ios you will get a pretty ugly overscroll behavior.

[image]

You will not be able to fix this behavior by using `ClampingScrollPhysics` instead of `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` because it will break `RefreshIndicator`.

A really good options is to override default `ScrollConfiguration` so it looks the same on both platforms

Here is a whole code for a custom widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// NOTE: this is really important, it will make overscroll look the same on both platforms
class _ClampingScrollBehavior extends ScrollBehavior {
  @override
  ScrollPhysics getScrollPhysics(BuildContext context) => ClampingScrollPhysics();
}

class NonScrollableRefreshIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Future<void> Function() onRefresh;

  const NonScrollableRefreshIndicator({
    required this.child,
    required this.onRefresh,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: ((_, constraints) {
        return RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: onRefresh,
          child: ScrollConfiguration(
            // Customize scroll behavior for both platforms
            behavior: _ClampingScrollBehavior(),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                  maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight
                ),
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

And it will behave like this on both platforms:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

More flexible solution is put your scrollable empty/error state widget into LayoutBuilder

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: constraints.maxHeight,
      child: ErrorState(
          subtitle: (snapshot.data as ErrorStateful).errorMessage),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Excelent solution!!! The best for me, thx

Answer (score 3):

**Is it possible without page that doesn't scroll?**

-No.

---

Please read the documentation of the parameter child in RefreshIndicator:

> The widget below this widget in the tree.
>
> The refresh indicator will be stacked on top of this child. The indicator will appear when child's Scrollable descendant is over-scrolled.
>
> Typically a [ListView] or [CustomScrollView].

---

**Is there a work-around?**

-Yes

You can put only one widget in the Listview's children list:

```
new RefreshIndicator(
  child: new ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Text('This is child with refresh indicator'),
    ],
  ),
  onRefresh: () {},
)
```

Comment: that's not really a workaround, that's exactly what the OP wants to avoid. A workaround would be to add a drag gesture that brings a refresh indicator from the top, if the release is about some amount of pixels below the start of the drag, then, trigger a the refresh method you want.'

Answer (score 2):

In **ListView.builder** use **physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()**

Example:

```
RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: () => _onRefresh(),
   child: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                     physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: 4,
                      addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                            return Text("Hello $position");
                          }
              ),
      ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is full code of what you need (Includes solved the problem of height when use `appBar`):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RefreshFullScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RefreshFullScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RefreshFullScreenState createState() => _RefreshFullScreenState();
}

class _RefreshFullScreenState extends State<RefreshFullScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; // Full screen width and height
    EdgeInsets padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding; // Height (without SafeArea)
    double netHeight = height - padding.top - kToolbarHeight; // Height (without status and toolbar)

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () {
          return Future.delayed(
            Duration(seconds: 1),
                () {
            },
          );
        }, child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: netHeight,
            )
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Global Key Solution

As the question asks explicitly for a solution to *"use a RefreshIndicator on a page that doesn't scroll."*

There is one way, but it might be considered hacky - it is possible define a `GlobalKey` to the `RefreshIndicator` to get a reference to the `RefreshIndicatorState`, which have a public `show` method hence there is no need for any scrollable widgets.

The downside is that since there is no scrolling, the indicator does not gradually come into the screen, rather it instantly appears and animates out.

```dart
final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> refreshIndicatorKey = GlobalKey();
```

For use cases that need to programmatically trigger the `RefreshIndicator` this approach might be interesting.

#### Example:

```dart
RefreshIndicator(
  key: refreshIndicatorKey,
  onRefresh: () async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  },
  child: Center(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        refreshIndicatorKey.currentState?.show(atTop: true);
      },
      child: const Text("Refresh"),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Complementing Gustavo answer you can use constraints to define the minimum size of SingleChildScrollView in this way

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CustomScrollView` with only one child `SliverFillRemaining` as my case for showing no data widget:

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
    SliverFillRemaining(
        child: Center(
        child: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).noData,
        ),
        ),
    )
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Going with @Gustavo's answer, in a situation whereby you want a refresh indicator also when the child content overflows, and you want a scroll at the same time, just wrap the child with another refreshing indicator with a scrolling physics, like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          child: RefreshIndicator(// wrap the child with a new RefreshIndicator here
              onRefresh: () {},
              child: SingleChildScrollView(// A new ScrollView Widget here
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),//A new scroll physics here
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('Hello World'), // You can make this a scroll overflown child
                  ))),
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `CustomScrollView`

```
 return RefreshIndicator(
       onRefresh: () {},
      child: Stack( // <--- use Stack
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // <--- set physics
            slivers: [
             ...
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```