# Flutter,How to let a child widget's height match parent in SingleChildScrollView?

Tags: listview, flutter, scrollview

I want to create a custom widget that can refresh list items.it looks like this:

```
...
Widget build(BuildContext context){
 return new RefreshIndicator(
   child:data.isEmpty?
     new SingleChildScrollView(
      child:new Center(
        child:new Text("this is a empty widget which needs to be center in parent!)
       ),
     )
     :
     new ListView.separated(...)
);
}
```

but it can't refresh when I touch the screen and move,I guess that is too short so not enough to be scroll?
I try to defined a `Container` instate of `Center` as the same result but if i define `1000` to `Container`'s `height`, it can be refresh now, how can i do?

Comment: The accepted answer can cause some problems. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62157637/11717888) is my optimized version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make sure the scroll view is always scrollable by using `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

You also need to make a large scrollable area.  You can use a `Container` and get the screen height with `MediaQuery`.

```
child: RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () async {
    print('onRefresh called');
  },
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Text('hello'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

This isn't a perfect solution.  The refresh function only works when the user drags the white space around the text.  If the user drags the text, then they don't see the refresh symbol.  Also they can scroll up a little.

The best solution is to use a PageView with vertical always-enabled scrolling and a single page:

```
child: RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () async {
    print('onRefresh called');
  },
  child: PageView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: Text('hello'),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

you can wrap your `RefreshIndicator` with a `LayoutBuilder` that has `viewportConstraints` and also wrap the `Center` widget with a `ConstrainedBox` (child of `SingleChildScrollView`) and set the `minHeight` to `viewportConstraints.maxHeight`. the `SingleChildScrollView` also need to be scrollable all the time so that the refresh indicator works, so you need to set `physics` to `const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`. in your case it'll be something like:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () async {},
          child: data.isEmpty
              ? SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                            "this is an empty widget which needs to be center in parent!")),
                  ),
                )
              : ListView.separated(...),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```